# How do I get a list of player without making its own class?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get records by their teamId for a group of players so far I have the following

```
public List<player> GetPlayersByTeamId(Guid teamId)
    {

        try
        {

            List<player> q = from _player in SoccerEntities.players.Where(a => a.teamId == teamId)
                             orderby _player
                             select _player;


            return q.ToList();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {


        }

    }
```

But I am getting the following errror

> Error 62  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  C:\new code\UniteCms\UniteCms\soccerCmsDal\SocerDataAccess.cs   299 42  soccerCmsDal

Comment: It's not a good idea to do `catch(Exception ex)`. It doesn't help you write good programs. You should only ever catch specific exceptions that you can meaningfully recover from.

Comment: I wasnt doing that in live code i obv take out my live code !

Comment: Excellent. Good to know. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Your linq expression is going to return an IQueryable not a List.

try this

```
 var q = from _player in SoccerEntities.players
                        Where a.teamId == teamId
                         orderby _player
                         select _player;

return q.ToList();
```

for future reference you can hover your cursor over the var keyword and it will tell you the inferred return type

and your are mixing query with method syntax. Probably would stick with one or the other.

Comment: mrsagent well what way would you prefare I right the query so that it returns a list suitable for grid data source ?

Comment: what im wanting is to work with live data set though so that i can delete objects from the grid will this work

Comment: You can still do a ToList() on the IQueryable to return a list.  You just can't have the explicit type name of the query as a list.  See my edited post.

Comment: but then I wont be able to get the live data item then sure i wont of a grid

Comment: You are going to want to use a ObservableCollection if you want to modify your collection and have it update the grid.  So you will need to return an ObservableCollection instead of a List.  The problem is you can't simply do a .ToObservableCollection() as you can with the .ToList().  But you can write an extension method like in this post.  You will extend the IQueryable<T> class instead of the IEnumerable<T> class.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984594/iqueryablea-to-observablecollectiona-where-a-anonymous-type